# Implementing "WHERE" Clause in MetaKey and MetaValue

Tags: mysql

I have a table with Meta keys with Its MetaValues as seen its structure and sample data below.

```
ID | Name | Last | Gender | Department | Dpt | Region | District | Status 
1 | Yeye | Two | Male | Ustawi wa Jamii | Sekondari Sayansi | two | Temeke | on
```

Then i have a query which output every MetaKey as a single column on each

```
SELECT 
  P.ID, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'first_name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Name, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'last_name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Last, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'Gender', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Gender, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'Department', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Department, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'position_title', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Dpt, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'region', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Region, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'district_dar', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS District, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'status_av', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Status 
FROM wp_users AS P 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS PM on PM.user_id = P.ID
```

The above query works fine but i want the data that will be outputed to have these two requirements,

> (i) Department should be "Health" 
> (II)Status should be "on"

So from my above SQL i tried to implement the "WHERE" clause but i'm getting error when i excute my query, see the query below

```
SELECT 
  P.ID, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'first_name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Name, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'last_name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Last, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'Gender', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Gender, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'Department', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Department, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'position_title', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Dpt, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'region', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Region, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'district_dar', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS District, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'status_av', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Status 
FROM wp_users AS P 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS PM on PM.user_id = P.ID 
WHERE PM.meta_key = 'Department=health' AND PM.meta_key = 'status_av=on' 
group by P.ID 
ORDER BY P.ID DESC LIMIT 30
```

Where am i doing wrong or any idea how should i implement the WHERE clause?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You are missing the GROUP BY clause in your first query. How can it work?

Comment: And meta_key field cannot have different values at the same time, so your where clause is impossible. You also seem to have combined meta_key and meta_value fields into a single string [literal.

Comment: @Shadow what query do you suggest will work?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel In what way should i put GROUP BY clause??

Comment: Same way as in the other (I guess) - `group by P.ID`. As it is you would only get a single row with a "random" ID. So I was corious how that could work for you.

Comment: And you still didn't aswer the question about the error. I see that will not give you the desired result - But it should at least run and return an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not a good table structure to do this, but if you have to, you can use a subquery to get all the `user_id` from `wp_usermeta` with your conditions first, for example:

```html
SELECT 
  P.ID, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'first_name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Name, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'last_name', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Last, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'Gender', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Gender, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'Department', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Department, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'position_title', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Dpt, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'region', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Region, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'district_dar', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS District, 
  MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'status_av', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS Status 
FROM wp_users AS P 
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS PM on PM.user_id = P.ID WHERE P.ID in (select user_id from wp_usermeta where meta_key='Department' and meta_value = 'health') and P.ID in (select user_id from wp_usermeta where meta_key='status_av' and meta_value = 'on') group by P.ID;
```

Maybe it's not a good way, but it will be an easy way if you don't have too much users in your table.

Comment: Thanks @Consitanto this query worked out, but why you said if i don't have too much users?? The system i'm building is going to have more than 5000 users. Can this cause a problem in the future???

Comment: You can check if you have index on `wp_usermeta.meta_key` and `wp_usermeta.meta_value`, if there's no, the subquery will take a long time if `wp_usermeta` have millions rows.

Comment: Now i get your point.